# Avoid Render Blocking by plugins which have both css and js dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a jQuery plugin it has `plugin.css` and `plugin.js` as dependencies and code is in `script.js`. I cant have plugin.js and script.js merged because i am using plugin only on one webpage of my website.

In order to make sure plugin.css is loaded before execution of plugin.js and script.js, normally I have no option but to have plugin.css in `<head>` which causes render blocking(until all resources in head are loaded,
browser doesnt render html).

**Normal Way:** Having CSS in `<head>` and JS before `</body>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/plugin.css">
</head>
<body>
    // content goes here
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="/js/plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Proposed Way:** Load CSS and JS via ajax calls and inject them when all of them are loaded,  using jQuery $.when promise

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    // content goes here
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script class="load-plugin">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var loadPlugin = {
                css : $.ajax({ url: $(".jquery-plugin-css").data("src")                                                      }),
                js : $.ajax({ url: $(".jquery-plugin-js").data("src")}),
            };
            var scriptJs = $.ajax({ url: $(".script-js").data("src") });
            $.when(loadPlugin.css, loadPlugin.js, scriptJs).then(function(){
                loadPlugin.css.done(function(data){ 
                    $(".jquery-plugin-css").html(data); 
                });
                loadPlugin.js.done(function(data){ 
                    $(".jquery-plugin-js").html(data); 
                });
                scriptJs.done(function(data){ 
                    $(".script-js").html(data); 
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style class="jquery-plugin-css" data-src="/css/plugin.css"></style>
    <script class="jquery-plugin-js" data-src="/js/plugin.js"></script>
    <script class="script-js" data-src="/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This improved my first render time from 3.4 secs to 2.4 secs and total page load time from 8.5secs to 8secs.

But this has some limitations:

1. Publicly hosted urls cant be used because the urls inside the plugin files like background-images inside css files if mentioned relative to their directory then the path changes after code is pasted into html.
2. As the injected code is not part of the source files or external scripts they cant be debugged in developer tools.

This way of lazyloading plugins has pros and equal amount of cons. Can anyone suggest is it worth it to do it this way or any better way to do things.

Comment: Could you just merge the JS into one file?

Comment: @Chad I can do it but the problem mentioned above is not due to plugin.js and script.js being as seperate files. my problem is to load css in <body> instead of placing it in <head> which causes render blocking and make sure that both plugin.js and script.js execute after plugin.css is loaded

Comment: @Chad i have lot of other things on the webpage i just isolated the code related to this issue. Please consider the above mentioned code as a boilerplate to the problem

Answer (score 0):

What I would try is:

1. Combine the JS files so that the dependent code is after plugin.js
2. Insert a script at the bottom of the page to dynamically load the CSS first and the combined JS second. If you need example code, you might look at https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadJS/ and https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/.

Using this approach, neither the CSS nor the JS blocks rendering. The CSS is appended to the DOM, so there should be no problems with relative URLs.

Comment: LoadCSS and LoadJS are simple tag insertions. how would you ensure that all resources are loaded before execution

I cant merge script.js with plugin.js because plugin.js is only on one page. script.js is on every page on my website

Comment: Since I don't know how the plugin.js and script.js relate to one another, or which need to wait for something, some general comments. What you should be trying to do is to load dependent code after what it depends on. You load the CSS first so that it is most likely active in time, but in any event the JS will not fail if it is still loading. If you have code that needs to wait for all resources, you wrap it in either a "load" or "DOMLoaded" event wrapper.